# Python dataframe t-test to find p values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am creating a logistic regression model to predict if it will rain tomorrow based off this dataset found on kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/weather-dataset-rattle-package

I wish to remove highly correlated features by keeping the feature with the lowest p value.

To do this, I have to conduct a t test on each feature, however I keep getting the result

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

My code to get the p value for "MinTemp" is:

```
from scipy import stats
ex = stats.ttest_ind(df2['RainTomorrow'],df2['MinTemp']) 
print(ex)
```

How can I extract the p value of each feature?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the null values from the data (assuiming you already converted text data into numbers):

```
from scipy import stats

#removing null values
df2 = df2[(df2['MinTemp'].notna()) & (df2['RainTomorrow'].notna())]

ex = stats.ttest_ind(df2['RainTomorrow'],df2['MinTemp']) 
print(ex)
```